# How to depth (z) test using rotation around the y axis?

Tags: java, math, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to sort some Quads by depth (Z) from the camera, but when the camera changes it's direction (Y axis - left and right), and position (the camera basically handles like DOOM's - which is a FPS without rotation on the X axis (up and down))

How should I go about doing this? I need a end result of a single "Z" value to be used to sort. I.E. "if myZVal is less than HisZVal than I'm closer."

This is my attempt so far: I though I  could check the radius length between my camera and the  Quads and soft by that, but it didn't seem to work, and upon firther thinking would mess up when I look at differant angles.

```
public static Vector<Quad> SortByZ(Vector<Quad> vec, Vector3f pos, Vector3f forward){
        Vector<Quad> sorted = new Vector<Quad>();

        for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
            Quad e = vec.get(i);
            e.myDepth = new Vector3f(0,0,0);




            Vector3f ray = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
            Vector3f.sub(pos, e.center, ray);
            e.myDepth.z = ray.lengthSquared();
                  }
    }
```

Comment: It almost sounds like you're doing raycasting here, rasterizing strips (quads) of the screen based on distance from the camera. If you think about how Wolfenstein 3D accomplished this on really limited hardware of the era, it traversed planes in a pre-built BSP tree rather than sorting anything. I think your solution is going to have to do with classifying the quads by their plane equation relative to the camera's orientation rather than a single depth value that somehow represents your entire quad :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting quads by an infinitely small point is generally a bad idea. Usually, quads have two things going for them that pixels on a screen (where depth is appropriate) do not:

1. **They have a facing angle** (*normal*)

   - If you render the quads they may not even be visible depending on which direction they face.
2. **They have variable area and can overlap** (*extent*)

   - Quads can be partially occluded by other quads with more distant centers, if their angles and extents are such that the two quads intersect or if one is sufficiently larger than the other.

You cannot use a single point to represent quads the same way you can pixels on the screen. There are additional cases that you must handle, such as partial occlusion or back-facing quads (in the case of rendering). When two quads intersect, then you wind up with a piece-wise evaluation to determine which quad is closer at specific points on the quad.

If instead of trying to treat your quads as points, you begin to think of them as finite sections of planes you should get much better results. Use the plane normal, together with the extent (distance the quad spans in each direction from its origin) to establish the actual spatial properties of your quads, and then you can handle all of the extra cases that do not apply to point vs. point sorting.

*It is also worth mentioning that quads do not need to be co-planar. Unlike triangles, you can wind up with a set of four points that do not all lie in the same plane. This is one of the reasons why triangles are preferred for rendering. Assuming you have quads with all 4 points in the same plane, then the math of "sorting" them becomes a lot simpler.*